# React Redux loading data on page load

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

New to redux and react in general, looking for some advice on best practice/how to.

When a page is loaded, I want to make an API call to my backend to get the data for my navigation menu, what's the best approach for this in React 18 with Class Components?

I have my store included from redux, I'm just not sure what format the actions and reducers should take, and how they're called.

Thanks!

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/quick-guide-for-fetching-api-data-using-react-redux-and-hooks-with-explanation-10503726bc6b

Comment: @NikitaChayka the linked article seems to be aimed at functional components rather than class components

Comment: There is an example with Class components in the article.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React/Redux - dispatch action on app load/init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563679/react-redux-dispatch-action-on-app-load-init)